# runtime.Caller(x) и defer

Tags: golang, runtime

С помощью функции [`runtime.Caller()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller) можно узнать данные о том, откуда произошёл вызов нынешней функции. Однако она крайне странно работает с функциями, отложенными через `defer`:

```golang
func main() {
    defer printLine("deferred") // Line 10
    printLine("direct")         // Line 11
} // Line 12

func printLine(s string) {
    _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
    fmt.Printf("%10s: %s:%d\n", s, filepath.Base(file), line)
}
```

Вывод:

```
    direct: main.go:11
  deferred: main.go:12
```

Хотя ожидался:

```
    direct: main.go:11
  deferred: main.go:10
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Jz6y0GkqTNW.

Можно ли как-то достать номер строки, на котором был вызван `defer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не нашёл, как можно это сделать напрямую. Однако подобный функционал можно реализовать через новую функцию с возвратом замыкания:

```golang
func main() {
    defer printDeferredLine("deferred")() // Line 10
    printLine("direct")                   // Line 11
} // Line 12

func printLine(s string) {
    _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
    fmt.Printf("%10s: %s:%d\n", s, filepath.Base(file), line)
}

func printDeferredLine(s string) func() {
    _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
    return func() {
        fmt.Printf("%10s: %s:%d\n", s, filepath.Base(file), line)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/mTFoW5WtEJq.

Вывод:

```
    direct: main.go:11
  deferred: main.go:10
```

Главное — не путать и не писать

```golang
defer printDeferredLine("deferred")
```

вместо

```golang
defer printDeferredLine("deferred")() // N.B. Extra parens.
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно так сделать:

```go
func main() {
    defer func() { printLine("deferred") }() // Line 10
    printLine("direct")                      // Line 11
} // Line 12
```

Возможно, кому-то будет полезно.